# Should I be including header files or source files for Google Test?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest

I'm learning how to use Google Test for one of my projects. When I include a header file I get a `LNK2019 unresolved external symbol...` error, however when I include the source file instead, it compiles successfully and the test runs. Have I made a mistake setting up my test project (I'm using Visual Studio 2019).

Edit: Sorry for any confusion, should I just have the Google Test project as a library and write my tests inside my actual project, including the gtest header? Right now, I've got my tests inside the Google Test project, with a main function inside it that runs the tests.

My current solution looks like this:

```
sln
    project
       src
    googleTest project
       tests
```

Should it look like this:

```
sln
    project
        src
        tests
    googleTest project (as library)
```

Comment: Never include source files. You should link the libraries to your project.

Comment: Always include the entire error you are asking about.  Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Maybe you did not use CMake to generate a Visual Studio project for the google test framework so that you can compile the binaries for the testing framework.

Comment: You include the header and link to the libraries.

Comment: ***Should it look like this*** I think that is more of a personal preference.

Comment: Your edit probably should have been a different question since it is a completely different topic unrelated to the first question about the linker error.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have not linked your test to google test library. Indeed check project settings.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/615008/linking-an-object-file-to-a-test-project.html). When you build a solution, each project under the solution gets built separately.

```
MyConsoleGameSolution
|_GameEngine
  |_include
  |_src
  |_...
|_MediaEngine
  |_include
  |_src
  |_...
|_AsteroidGame   (Suppose this has built successfully)
  |_include
  |_src
    |_ship.cpp
  |_x64\Debug\ship.obj  (Result of successful build)
  |_...
|_AsteroidGameTester
  |_include
  |_src
    |_shipTester.cpp   (Say this uses a "Ship" class from AsteroidGame/ship.cpp)
  |_...
```

So object files from the `AsteroidGame` project are *not* automatically linked when you compile `AsteroidGameTester`.

You'd get the `LNK2019 unresolved external symbol...` error if you went to build `AsteroidGameTester` and the compiler tries to build `shipTester.cpp`. This is because `shipTester.cpp` doesn't know where definitions for `Ship` class are (which is defined in `ship.obj`).

So you must specify that the compiler should *link* `ship.obj` from `AsteroidGame` with other object files from `AsteroidGameTester`.

You do this by going into **Properties** > **Linker** > **Input** > **Additional Dependencies** for the `AsteroidGameTester` project. Edit **Additional Dependencies**
to include the fullpath to ship.obj (ie., `$(SolutionDir)\MyConsoleGameSolution\AsteroidGame\x64\Debug\ship.obj` or use `...\x64\Debug\*.obj` for convenience, if appropriate)